# A Recursive Formula For Generalized Josephus problem

Tags: combinatorics, recursion

The [Josephus Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem) asks where to start taking out every kth person in the circle consisted of n people, such that you are the last "survivor".

The following recursive formula is given:
$$\begin{align}
f(1,k)&=1, \\
f(n,k)&=((f(n-1,k)+k-1) \bmod n )+1.
\end{align}$$

But this is not enough explanation, so I don't get where does it come from.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You mean wiki explanation in [general case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem#The_general_case) is not enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me explain the idea. 
Assume that indices start from 0.
Take N = 6 and K = 3
So initial arrangement looks something like

> 0->1->2->3->4->5->0.... like a circle.

After round 1 , '2' is eliminated .

> 0->1->2->3->4->5->0->1...
>
> `....(k)->0->1->2->3->`
>
> > here (k) denotes the person is killed

Since we ought to start from the last position we killed, so lets look at the updated indices.

> `Old Index` |  `New Index`
>
> > `3` | `0`
> >
> > `4` | `1`
> >
> > `5` | `2`
>
> and so on.... 
>   looking closely we can easily see after each round
>
> > `OldPosition = (newPosition+k)mod N`

Where N is the number of people left before the round started.

Also `OldPosition` signifies `f(N,K)`

and `New Position` signifies `f(N-1,K)` as one person has already been killed.

So putting it back to `OldPostion = (newPostion+k) mod N`
we get

`f(N,K) = ( f(N-1,K)+ K ) mod N`

But this is done only if u have indices starting from 0. If u want to rearrange for indices starting from 1, you can rearrange it to get the above result.

I found a beautiful paper on this

http://blue.butler.edu/~phenders/InRoads/MathCounts8.pdf

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Welcome to [cs.se]! We aim to be a source of information, rather than just a link farm so it would be great if you could at least summarize the contents of the paper and explain how it answers the question.

Comment: thanks @DavidRicherby , i have updated my answer on this.

Comment: For the `rearrange ` part, could put it this way: If index start from `1`, then just add `1` to the result when index start from `0`. Similarly, if index start from `t`, just add `t` to the result when index start from `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Knuth goes through this in the first chapter of his classic math textbook, Concrete Mathematics. His treatment is very understandable.